# Show recursive row count in Devexpress XtraGrid GroupRow

Tags: c#, recursion, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a gridview with multiple groups and I use the `CustomDrawGroupRow` Event to display the row count for each group:

```
private void gridView_CustomDrawGroupRow(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowObjectCustomDrawEventArgs e)
{
    var view = (GridView)sender;
    var info = (GridGroupRowInfo)e.Info;
    var caption = info.Column.Caption;
    if (info.Column.Caption == string.Empty)
    {
        caption = info.Column.ToString();
    }
    info.GroupText = $"{caption} : {info.GroupValueText} ({view.GetChildRowCount(e.RowHandle)})";
}
```

[image: Grid View]

Now I would like to display the row count recursively, so that the first level shows a count of 2171 (1913 + 135 + 123).

This is what I have tried, but it throws a **StackOverflowException** and I cannot see the problem here:

```
private void gridView_CustomDrawGroupRow(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowObjectCustomDrawEventArgs e)
{
    var view = (GridView)sender;
    var info = (GridGroupRowInfo)e.Info;
    var caption = info.Column.Caption;
    if (info.Column.Caption == string.Empty)
    {
        caption = info.Column.ToString();
    }
    info.GroupText = $"{caption} : {info.GroupValueText} ({GetRowCountRecursive(view, e.RowHandle)})";
}

private int GetRowCountRecursive(GridView view, int rowHandle)
{
    int totalCount = 0;
    int childrenCount = view.GetChildRowCount(rowHandle);
    for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
    {
        var childRowHandle = view.GetChildRowHandle(rowHandle, i);
        totalCount += GetRowCountRecursive(view, childRowHandle);
    }
    return totalCount;
}
```

Comment: It seems that you GetChildRowCount call always returns 1 or greater number during looping at least one of your first level children rows. Can you check this scenario through breakpoint? Also check this out, do you use ServerMode? https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T393756

Comment: The ServerMode property and this link is related to ASPxGridView. I'm using the XtraGrid for winforms.

Comment: In case the children rows of level 1 (the Category rows) are group rows themselves, probably your GetChildRowHandle() function call will not return the correct result. In this case the call of GetChildRowCount() during the next GetRowCountRecursive call wiil get even more mixed up results. Can you check if a invalid row handle or a wrong number generally returns during the for loops?

Comment: GetChildRowHandle() returns a negative integer if the row is a group row, but this is OK. I found the problem and I will post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GroupRowInfo.ChildControllerRowCount` property to get the row count. The instance of `GroupRowInfo` class you can get from `GridGroupRowInfo.RowKey` property.
Here is example:

```
private void gridView1_CustomDrawGroupRow(object sender, RowObjectCustomDrawEventArgs e)
{
    var view = (GridView)sender;
    var info = (GridGroupRowInfo)e.Info;
    var caption = info.Column.Caption;
    if (info.Column.Caption == string.Empty)
    {
        caption = info.Column.ToString();
    }

    var groupInfo = info.RowKey as GroupRowInfo;

    info.GroupText = $"{caption} : {info.GroupValueText} ({groupInfo?.ChildControllerRowCount})";
}
```

Here is the screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I was missing to check if `childRowHandle` is a group row with `IsGroupRow()`. If not, the recursion have to stop and `totalCount` need to be increased by 1.

```
private int GetRowCountRecursive(GridView view, int rowHandle)
{
    int totalCount = 0;
    int childrenCount = view.GetChildRowCount(rowHandle);
    for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
    {
        var childRowHandle = view.GetChildRowHandle(rowHandle, i);
        if (view.IsGroupRow(childRowHandle))
        {
            totalCount += GetRowCountRecursive(view, childRowHandle);
        }
        else
        {
            totalCount++;
        }
    }
    return totalCount;
}
```

[image: Grid View]